# How to remove label name from count plot graphic in Seaborn?

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, count, namespaces

The main question is how to remove the "Label" namespace in the graphic if I have a count plot of three dataset files? I am using the Seaborn module.

```
#Importing the libraries
 import pandas as pd
 import numpy as np
 import seaborn as sb

#Reading the files 
train_filename = 'train.csv'
test_filename = 'test.csv'
valid_filename = 'valid.csv'

train_news = pd.read_csv(train_filename)
test_news = pd.read_csv(test_filename)
valid_news = pd.read_csv(valid_filename)

#Data observation
 def data_obs():
     print("Training dataset size:")
     print(train_news.shape)
     print(train_news)

     print("Testing dataset size:")
     print(test_news.shape)
     print(test_news)

     print("Validation dataset size:")
     print(valid_news.shape)
     print(valid_news)

  print(data_obs())
```

Here is the result what I got from data [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLQeI.png)

[image]

Also, I am using the LIAR dataset and it has the following features:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/026ld.png)

Comment: Are you using seaborn?

Comment: Yes, I am using seaborn

Comment: Please include the rest of the code

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack. There are a few things, first post code as text and not as an image. Second, show your data because I think that the problem is what and how you load but cannot check that. Lastly, it would be nice to see how you would like it to be looking.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
g = sb.countplot(x='Label', data=dataFile, palette="hls")

g.set(xticklabels=[])   # To remove the ticklabels
g.set(xlabel=None)      # To remove the "Label"
```

Comment: I do not think that this is the problem, I think that ma_brr124 means the empty col...

Answer (score 0):

I tested and just realized that when I printed just train and test data I got the correct chart, but when I added validation data it shows an additional empty column called "Label"